# How to click an element which is not loaded in DOM using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, scroll, webdriver, horizontal-scrolling

There is div with many internal divs as seen in screenshot

As seen in screenshot there are 6col and 1 checkbox col so total 7 columns are visble. But there are more columns till col40 if you scroll right. But the divs of all 40 cols are not loaded at one time but loads upon scrolling

I want to validate if col35-col40(or any random col after col6) are visible and is editable and clickable.

I have tried below options but none of them working.

1. Javascript executor (with or without webelement for scrolling horizontally)
2. Robot keys.tab/keys.cntrl+keys.end/all keys option using which we can manually go to that particular column
3. Sendkeys
4. Action class
5. Zoom out (this is not the feasible/ correct way to do but still tried but this is also not working as expected)

Need some solution for this.

Please note: The scroll bar is not having any identifier/attribute but it is inside the main div without any unique identity.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If your element is not loaded yet in DOM, you cannot perform any actions on it since is not there.
A workaround for your problem is to design a method to scroll until your element is available in DOM, and then perform desired actions (check, click etc).
Note that you cannot scroll to your element (because is not there) so you can scroll to another reference (locator) or based on pixels using javascript executor object.